# How do I change the row color if the 'difference' value is - in the Asp.Net DataTable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi I want the row to be red if the value is negative in the 'difference' field in the Asp.Net DataTable. The 'difference' value is the difference between the current stock and the safety stock. How can I do that?

## view file

```
<table id="den" class="table table-condensed table-hover dataTable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Safety Stock</th>
                                    <th>Actual</th>
                                    <th>Difference</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Safety Stock</th>
                                    <th>Actual</th>
                                    <th>Difference</th>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                            <tbody>
                            @Html.Raw(ViewBag.den)
                            </tbody>
</table>

     @section _script{<script src="/Content/bundles/datatablescripts.bundle.js"></script>  }
  @section script{

<script>
    $(function () {
        var table = $('#den').DataTable()
</script>
  }
```

## controller file

```
public ActionResult StockStatus()
    {
        foreach (var item in filled_eyes)
        {
            foreach (var stock in products_in_eye)
            {
                var difference= available_stock- stok.SafetyStock;
                var available_stock = list.Where(x => x.MovementType== 1).Sum(x => x.Piece) - list.Where(x => x.MovementType== 0).Sum(x => x.Piece);
                string col = difference < 0 ? "test" : "";

                table +=
                "<tr class='" + col + "'>" +
                "<td>" + stock.safety_stock + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + available_stock + "</td>"+
                "<td>" + difference + "</td>" ;
            }
        }
        ViewBag.den = table;
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you just add css for class test:

```css
<style>
.test{
font-weight: bold 
}
</style>
```